# Strange model behavior when using InstancedMesh with CameraSync (threebox)

Tags: javascript, three.js, mapbox-gl-js, threebox

#### Description

After adding the mesh of the gltf model to THREE.InstancedMesh, I modified the scaling, and the rendered effect seems to have lost some vertices

#### Reproduction steps

1. Adding custom layers using mapboxgl
2. Load the model using three gltfloader in the mapboxgl custom layer
3. Adding gltf mesh using THREE.InstancedMesh

#### Code

```js
loader.load(
        "https://threejs.org/examples/models/gltf/Flower/Flower.glb",
        function (gltf) {
          const p = projectToWorld(origin);

          const model = gltf.scene;

          const _stemMesh = model.getObjectByName("Stem");
          const _blossomMesh = model.getObjectByName("Blossom");

          const stemGeometry = _stemMesh.geometry.clone();
          const blossomGeometry = _blossomMesh.geometry.clone();

          const stemMaterial = _stemMesh.material;
          const blossomMaterial = _blossomMesh.material;

          const stemMesh = new THREE.InstancedMesh(
            stemGeometry,
            stemMaterial,
            1
          );
          const blossomMesh = new THREE.InstancedMesh(
            blossomGeometry,
            blossomMaterial,
            1
          );

          stemMesh.instanceMatrix.setUsage(THREE.DynamicDrawUsage);
          blossomMesh.instanceMatrix.setUsage(THREE.DynamicDrawUsage);

          const defaultTransform = new THREE.Matrix4()
            .makeRotationX(Math.PI)
            .multiply(new THREE.Matrix4().makeScale(1, 1, 1));

          stemGeometry.applyMatrix4(defaultTransform);
          blossomGeometry.applyMatrix4(defaultTransform);

          stemMesh.instanceMatrix.needsUpdate = true;
          blossomMesh.instanceMatrix.needsUpdate = true;

          const dummy = new THREE.Object3D();

          let pos = projectToWorld([118.61113, 32.06318, 0]);

          for (let i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
            dummy.position.copy(pos);
            dummy.scale.set(10, 10, 10);
            // dummy.scale.set(100, 100, 100);
            dummy.updateMatrix();
            stemMesh.setMatrixAt(i, dummy.matrix);
            blossomMesh.setMatrixAt(i, dummy.matrix);
          }

          const group = new THREE.Group();

          group.add(stemMesh);
          group.add(blossomMesh);

          world.add(group);

          map.triggerRepaint(); }
      );
```

#### Live example

Use the right mouse button to drag and drop the map to select it.
Alternatively, modify the code dummy. scale. set (5, 5, 5);

- [codepen](https://codepen.io/xiaxiangfeng/pen/KKJyvoV)

#### Screenshots

#### Version

all

Is it related to camera synchronization? How can I modify it